# Can a windows domain admin access non shared files on a PC connected, but not joined to the domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, domain

My company allows users to bring their own devices into the office and use the internal network due to our fast internet connection. These devices/PC's are **not** joined to the company Windows Domain.

Can anyone on the domain, including domain admin accounts, access files or shares on these devices/PC's without the owners knowledge? Are users personal files safe?

Comment: Ask your sysadmin at work. We're a site for professional sysadmins only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Windows system is not joined to a domain, it only knows about its local user accounts; the only way to access its files is to provide valid user credentials for the system. So, unless you are using a very easy-to-guess password, you should be safe.

The only exception would be if you have enabled guest sharing (which is disabled by default); then, everyone could access files shared to guest users, without needing any authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I assumed as much, but as a junior sysadmin wanted to check. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In general no, your PC will not accept domain credentials and assuming you don't have any open shares then no one will be able to connect to your PC.  However this isn't to say you will go undetected, there are many products that let network admins detect unauthorized hosts on networks.  I also strongly advise against this practice as you are putting your corporate network at risk and could lead to your termination.

Comment: Thanks. It's part of a 'bring your own device' scheme and all above board, but I can see the risks for most companies.

Answer (score 0):

Does your IT team install a client on your machine to help them with support issues? Have they changed any settings?

If so this may enable remote file system access for them.

I have used Kaseya for remote support which uses a plugin on client machines which allows full access to the remote file system with no notification to the user.